# python garbage collector go mad

Tags: python, ssl, memory-leaks, garbage-collection

Python 2.7.12, Ubuntu 16.04.

Simple server application that checks email box every 10 seconds and writes in debug log that there are no messages. Mailbox is really empty, so application really do nothing else. Single threaded. Doesn't use any custom C-extensions. Usually uses 17 Mb of memory or something like this.

But after some hours, may be a day, it suddenly starts to grow in memory up to 8 gigabytes, consumes 100% CPU and doesn't write debug log any more.

I read http://tech.labs.oliverwyman.com/blog/2008/11/14/tracing-python-memory-leaks/ , run my application under pdb, wait for a night and look that objgraph can show. Nothing. There are no object types, that grown widely, all counts are about normal (I firstly check with application in normal state).

Then I try to use https://pythonhosted.org/Pympler/muppy.html Like this:

```
(Pdb) from pympler import muppy
(Pdb) all_objects = muppy.get_objects()
*** MemoryError:
```

Then after a while I saw in system monitor, that process pdb now consumes only 2Gb of memory! But it single threaded (I check with ps) and my application was stopped, so somehow 6Gb just disappears...

End of story: after some experiments I accidentally found how I can in this pdb-session quickly go to 100% CPU and 8-12 Gb. Just call gc.collect() and it will do. muppy.get_objects() has the same effect.

But in pdb in a few minutes after gc.collect() finished resources will shrink back to 2Gb, it seems that in application situation is not the same.

gc.collect() returns 0, by the way.

I suspect that someone corrupts python heap and I suspect SSL module (just because it is complex, don't have any more specific reasons). I use it when connect to mailbox via IMAP over SSL using standard imaplib + some my code that makes it understand timeouts (and all my code are in Python).

What else can I do to find/fix problem? May be some good memory inspection tool or a known bug in python libraries?

---

Guys, I get him! Seems that GC problems was just visual effects, real problem here:

```
# IMAP with timeouts
class NonBlockingSSL_IMAP(imaplib.IMAP4):
    def __init__(self, timeout, *args, **kwargs):
        self.timeout = timeout
        imaplib.IMAP4.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    ....

    def read(self, size):
        readed = 0
        buffer = []

        # ssl socket is not entirely normal socket, so may be there are some data
        # and select do not know about them. So we should dry socket first.
        dried = False

        while readed < size:
            if dried:
                self.wait_for(recv=self.sock)
            try:
                data = self.sslobj.recv(size - readed)                
                buffer.append(data)   # <----- here !!!!
                readed += len(data)
            except ssl.SSLWantReadError:
                dried = True
            except socket.error as se:
                if se.errno != errno.EAGAIN:
                    # something bad happened
                    raise se
                dried = True
        return ''.join(buffer)

    ....

    def wait_for(self, recv=None, send=None):
        rd = [recv] if recv is not None else []
        wr = [send] if send is not None else []

        ready_r, ready_w, _ = select.select(rd, wr, [], self.timeout)

        if not ready_r and not ready_w:
            raise socket.error(errno.EAGAIN, "timeout")
```

If recv return empty string, I add it to buffer, and do not increase readed (cause len == 0). And it may be an infinite loop. And as a result we have one very big list of empty strings -- there are no additional objects at all (cause all '' are one object; hello, objgraph). Just one really-really big list. And probably Python can not process it correctly, and I can understand it.